# Nginx Change Request from GET to POST with one specific URL

Tags: nginx

I have a site all URL use method get, but one of them use post, so I want to resolve this in nginx

But the specific URL say me file not found

Comment: How are you accessing the URL - through program or though browser?

Comment: I access throught broser